# how do i creat a condition like c_pressed?

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

Could someone tell me what am i doing wrong? or if it even possible to add a condition when c_pressed while using the same arg=5.

I'm trying to use the same arg=5 for both M and Mc but with one of them working while c is pressed

```
local M_coords = {{ x = 0, y = 7 }} 
local Mc_coords = {{ x = 0, y = 5}}
local M = false
local Mc = false

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 7 then
    M = false
    Mc = false
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then
        M = true
    Mc = false
      
      S = 11
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and M then
      local dy = 0
      repeat
         for i, v in ipairs(M_coords) do
            suppress(v.x , v.y +dy)
         end
         dy = dy + 0.011
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 and "c_pressed" then
        M = false
    Mc = true
      
      S = 11
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and Mc then
      local dy = 0
      repeat
         for i, v in ipairs(Mc_coords) do
            suppress(v.x , v.y +dy)
         end
         dy = dy + 0.011
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) 
   
   end  
end
```

Comment: What does `c_pressed` mean?  To check if `Ctrl` key is pressed invoke `IsModifierPressed("Ctrl")` or `IsModifierPressed("LCtrl")` or `IsModifierPressed("RCtrl")`

Comment: C on the keyboard. Is it possible to have something like " elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 and "c_pressed" then " ?

Answer (score 0):

GHUB is unable to monitor status of usual keys (digits, letters) on the keyboard.  It could monitor only mouse buttons, lock keys (capslock, etc), modifiers (ctrl, alt, etc) and G-keys (on Logitech keyboard).
As a workaround you can use third-party software (such as AHK) to map `C` keyboard key to `Back` mouse button (aka VK_XBUTTON1), and then in GHUB Lua code invoke `IsMouseButtonPressed(4)` to determine whether `C` is pressed.

Comment: so can i do it like " elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 and IsModifierPressed("LCtrl") then

Comment: @Max - Yes.....

Comment: It still run the M_Coords while holding the LCtrl instead of Mc_coords after changing it. What am i doing wrong?  elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 and IsModifierPressed("LCtrl") then
        M = false
 Mc = true

Comment: The condition of the previous branch `event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5` should be appended with  `and not IsModifierPressed("LCtrl")`

Comment: it still won't activate Mc_coords, is it because it can't detect that i'm holding LCtrl?

Comment: Upload (to pastebin.com) your last version of the Lua script.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/BV3Du1uU

Comment: This script should not work at all.  It contains syntax error `and and not IsModifierPressed("LCtrl")` (double `and`)

Comment: ya i removed that extra "and". As to containing syntax error, It didn't show any error to me thats why i thought it was ok.

Comment: Variable `S` not defined.  `MoveMouseRelative` expects integer arguments, not fractional.